# How to remove duplicate Facebook Access Tokens?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have 100 Active Facebook access tokens.
For each account I have more than one access token.

I want to keep only one token for each account and want to delete the others.
And i don't want to do this manually so please post a PHP script which check all the tokens and keep only one active token for each account.

Comment: Why are you saving these hundreds of token for each user?

Answer (score 0):

In such a case the simplest way to validate an access token is to issue the following request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=@accesstoken
```

If the provided access token is not valid or expired Facebook will just return an error message of some sort. Such as :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 190, 
    "error_subcode": 467
  }
}
```

For a valid access token the result will somehow look like this

```
{
   "id": "ID_VALUE"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to validate a token. I said i have VALID 100 access tokens. but the problem is that:
"FOR ONE ACCOUNT I HAVE MORE THAN ONE TOKEN."

Comment: and i want to keep only one token for each account and want to remove the other token of the same account